# In Reactjs, how to show input text that is modified from the actual value

Tags: html, reactjs

I've got an input field that I would like to show in a currency format, but any values be a simple integer.  Ie. I would like the user to see *$5.00* but the actual value of the input to be *5* (which is also the value being passed to the component).

My original stab at this was to have:

```
<input type="text" onChange={this.setValue} value={inputValue}>
  {inputValue === '' ? 'None' : I18n.l('currency', inputValue)}
</input>
```

But when I run I get an error:

> invariant.js? Uncaught Invariant Violation: input is a void element tag and must not have `children` or use `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

I thought this would be a good question for the StackOverflow crowd, surely someone has run into this requirement before?

Thanks for any input regarding this! (no pun intended)

Answer (score 2):

`input` types can't have children, but you could display the currency to the left of the input perhaps?

```
<span>$</span>
<input type="text" onChange={this.setValue} value={inputValue} />
```

Or even create a set of inputs to represent the different parts of the currency value:

```
<span>$</span>
<input type="text" onChange={this.setDollars} value={inputDollars} />
<span>.</span>
<input type="text" onChange={this.setCents} value={inputCents} />
```

Or even just have a preview:

```
<input type="text" onChange={this.setValue} value={inputValue} />
<div>Value is: {inputValue === '' ? 'None' : I18n.l('currency', inputValue)}</div>
```

Comment: That's unfortunate that I can't do a separate value/display value, but this makes sense.  I think your very first suggestion might work, doesn't look too bad.

Answer (score 2):

`input` is self closing html element therefore you cannot pass children to it (react's invariant error). You can display currency in different element (e.g. span):

```
<div>
  <input type="text" onChange={this.setValue} value={inputValue} />
  <span>{inputValue === '' ? 'None' : I18n.l('currency', inputValue)}</span>
</div>
```

You can also create your own input element which accept children, e.g.:

```
const MyTextInput = props => (
  <div>
    <input type="text" onChange={this.props.onChange} value={this.props.value} />
    <span>
      {props.children}
    </span>
  </div>
);

// ... and use it

<MyTextInput onChange={this.setValue} value={inputValue}>
  {inputValue === '' ? 'None' : I18n.l('currency', inputValue)}
</MyTextInput>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that would show 2 values, non?  Ie it would show `5 $5.00` which would be odd visually.  Good to know about the children, makes sense now.

Comment: I like the separate component, nice touch!  Unfortunately I just think it would look weird to have 2 values showing (one integer and a currency right next to it)  Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @MarkKadlec you are welcome. I would just put `$` before and `.00` after the input element and play around with styles.